# How can I selectively blank out SSAS aggregative levels?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I'm trying to build a cube which will contain a history of product prices by on-line sellers.  So, it has one simple "fact" table and three dimension tables.  The fact looks like this:

product_id
   seller_id,
   price_date,
   product_price

and the dimensions are product, seller, and date.  The product dimensions rolls up into manufacturers (so products can be grouped by manufacturers).  The seller dimensions just has the seller name, and the date dimension has the normal complement of date levels.

I'd like to have the cube respond to users by not displaying any data unless the user has drilled down into the sku level, and the individual seller level, although I wouldn't mind having the aggregations be averages on the manufacturer level.

But for the date dimension I would like the cube to display lastnonempty.

When I choose lastnonempty as the aggregation property, the prices get summed along the manufacturer and seller dimensions, which is wrong.

Here is a sample of what I'd like to see:

```
fact table:
 date      product    manufacturer    seller     price
 1/1/2000  sku1       manu1           seller1    $10.00
 1/2/2000  sku1       manu1           seller1    $12.00
```

cube result

```
manu1           -
  sku1         -
    Jan 2000     $12.00
       1/1/2000  $10.00
       1/2/2000  $12.00
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,  --sw

Answer (score 1):

Be careful actually nulling out subtotals since this makes it very difficult for users to even start a PivotTable. I blogged about this dilemma and a solution here:
http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2012/6/8/na-for-subtotals

So it is possible. Try something like:

```
scope( [Product].[Product].[All], [Measures].[Price] );
 this = IIf(IsEmpty([Measures].[Price]),null,0);
 Format_String(this) = ";;"; //format zeros as blank
end scope;
```

Then repeat that code to blank out the manufacturer and seller subtotals.

You can switch the AggregateFunction on your Price measure to LastNonEmpty. But I tend to prefer LastChild for the reasons mentioned [here](http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2008/02/06/last-non-empty-affairs.aspx) and [here](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2009/2/19/lastnonempty-gotchas). It does add a little more MDX to use LastChild as I explained in that second article. And you may be ok with LastNonEmpty if every product is snapshotted every day.